# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function slick car

Tags: jquery, carousel, typeerror

I've read through and couldn't find a solution tailored to my problem

I am trying to get the slick carousel to work. I've gotten it to work on jsbin shown here:
http://jsbin.com/gojozobemi/1/edit?html,output

However when working on my desktop it displays a error in the dev console saying "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"
Heres some of my desktop's code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.single-items').slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        adaptiveHeight: true
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="single-items">
    <div>
        <img src="http://wallpapercartoon.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/o-DOUG-facebook.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130803215442/nickelodeon/images/e/e2/Tumblr_lvjvhxwDiM1r6hffko1_400.jpg">
    </div>

    <div>
        <img src="http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/303/b/4/pork_chop_by_barontremaynecaple-d6sdm6s.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm stumped as to why this would work on JSBin and not on my desktop, any help would be appreciated

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 9]><html class="lt-ie10" lang="en" > <![endif]-->
<html class="no-js" lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- If you delete this meta tag World War Z will become a reality -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <title>Coffee Site</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.css" />

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
  <script src="js/slickini.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="contain-to-grid sticky">
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
      <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="name">
          <h1><a href="#">Coffee Site</a></h1>
        </li>
        <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <section class="top-bar-section">
        <!-- Right Nav Section -->
        <ul class="right">
          <li class="has-form">
            <div class="row collapse">
              <div class="large-8 small-9 columns">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Find Stuff">
              </div>
              <div class="large-4 small-3 columns">
                <a href="#" class="alert button expand">Search</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Left Nav Section -->
        <ul class="left">
          <li class="has-dropdown">
            <a href="#">Left Button Dropdown</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
              <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a>
              </li>
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Active link in dropdown</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </section>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <!---main content goes here-->
  <div class="single-items">
    <div>
      <img src="http://wallpapercartoon.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/o-DOUG-facebook.jpg">
    </div>

    <div>
      <img src="http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130803215442/nickelodeon/images/e/e2/Tumblr_lvjvhxwDiM1r6hffko1_400.jpg">
    </div>

    <div>
      <img src="http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/303/b/4/pork_chop_by_barontremaynecaple-d6sdm6s.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>


  <script>
    $(document).foundation();
  </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you please post some code along with your jsbin link? Thank you.

Comment: fixed, let me know if theres anything else I can add that would help. This is the first time I've ever asked a question here.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see why though it wouldn't work. Did you load jquery before loading your script?

Comment: my entire html is at the bottom let me know if somethings out of place because im completely stumped

Comment: None of the urls are a 404 error right? Relatedly, why are you loading jquery twice (once at the top and once at the bottom)?

Comment: I took the top one out after this, and I have one 404
http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.css.map 404 (Not Found)

Comment: That probably shouldn't affect anything...

Comment: i wish we could move this to a chat but do you see anything else that could be causing the problem? im at my wits end here haha

Comment: Looks like thread opener was including multiple versions of jquery (vendor/jquery) and (jquery-1.11.1.min.js)..

Answer (score 2):

Just add **http** or **https** to your jquery.slick `script` reference.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.min.js"></script>
```

You probably have a static web site in your desktop (without a web server) so the browser doesn't know how to resolve the reference without the http or https.
As the JSBin like any hosted web site runs on a web server the browser knows how to resolve the reference. It adds **http** or **https** taking the value of the site's URL.

***Do the same for your `link` css reference.**

Comment: well i guess I should update

I sorta fixed my problem

sorta meaning i gave up on slick carousel and went with owl carousel which is working perfectly. 

thank you everyone for the help!!!

Comment: @CodyCarmichael please if it works feel free to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the double instance of jquery ('vendor/jquery.js' and 'jquery-1.11.1.min.js') are loaded..  As far as I know, slick.js got issues with older versions of jquery, too.